# As3 Best solution about arrays

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

Let me cut to the main issue, I have a grid which is 50 by 50. And I need a way of having a true or false variable for each cell in the grid and the default value would be false, every time the method is called.

I need the array so I can see which cells I have visited so I don't need to revisited them for my path finding system that I'm working on .

But currently I have a double array[] [] which I need to loop every time I use this method. (up to 3 times a second but mostly never) which means looping 2500 value. Which doesn't sound very good. What would be the best solution, is this the best solution or am I missing something stupid.

Hope you can help and point me into the right direction.

Comment: The first thing to do is to look at are Vectors. Vectors outperform Arrays, espescialy if you are using boolean values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible improvement is using a single-dimensional vector, maybe wrapped into a class, that will contain 2500 elements and its indexes would mean (width*50+height). Like this:

```
private var _visited:Vector.<Boolean>;
function checkVisited(x:int,y:int):Boolean {
    return _visited(x*50+y); // x and y are in 0-49 range
}
```

Vectors can be two-dimensional should you need them, you declare vector of vectors like this:

```
var _visited:Vector.<Vector.<Boolean>>;
```

Initialize with pushing the filled `Vector.<Boolean>` once, then just change the elements as you do with a normal array.

The main advantage of vectors is that they are solid, that is, if there are 50 elements in a vector, you are sure that there exists a value at any index from 0 to 49 (even if null, or NaN in case of Numbers), this also makes internal processing of vectors easier, as the Flash engine can calculate proper memory location by just using the index and the link to the vector, which is faster than first referencing the array about whether there is a value at that index, if yes, get its memory location, then reference.

Comment: Thanks for this reply, never through of doing "_visited(x*50+y);", So now if the value is null, i can assume that its false. I do really appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience of making tile based games with different grids I usually have a Tile class, that will contain all your necessary values, most typical would be:

- posX:int
- posY:int
- isChecked:Boolean

You can add as many as you need for your app.

Then I have a Grid class that will create you grid and have some useful methods like giving neighbor tiles.

In the Grid class I make the grid this way:

```
public var tileLineArray:Vector.<Tile>;
public var tile2dArray:Vector.<Vector.<Tile>>;

public function makeGrid(w:int, h:int):void
{
    tileLineArray = new Vector.<Tile>();
    tile2dArray = new Vector.<Vector.<Tile>>();

    for (var i:int = 0; i < gridWidth; i++)
    {
        var rowArray:Vector.<Tile> = new Vector.<Tile>();
        for (var j:int = 0; j < gridHeight; j++)
        {
            var t:Tile = new Tile();
            t.posX = i;
            t.posY = j;
            tileLineArray.push(t);
            rowArray.push(t);
        }
        tile2dArray.push(rowArray);
    }
}
```

What it will give you is that you can access tiles in a single line to by coordinates x,y;

- var myTile:Tile = tileLineArray[lineID];
- var myTile:Tile = tile2dArray[targetX][targetY];

I use Vectors in this example as they outperform Arrays and you keep the type of the stored object intact.

It is not a problem for Flash to loop through the array; if you want improve performance, `break` the loop if you've done all what you wanted with it, `continue` the loop if the tile does not meet the requirements and you don't need to process it.

Also, having a 2d array can improve performance, since you can process only the area of the array that you need.

One more advice is not to be afraid to make X more smaller arrays to store some data from the bigger array and loop trough the small ones. As the data of the arrays is not a primitive (int, uint etc.) but a Class, it will hold a pointer/reference to the object, so you're not actually making copies of the objects every time.

Comment: `public var tile2dArray:Vector.<Vector.<Tile>>;` should be a 2D vector. Fixed that for you.

Comment: oh, thanks, I made a typo since I wrote it directly here and not in the IDE. Herp-derp.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i never knew that a vector outperform Arrays, you learn something new every day, im not 100% sure if this would be the best solution for this program im making currently, but i have programs down the line which this will come in hand. I appreciate the amount of detail that you have given here, Thanks again.